# Java merge Objects (Json, ObjectMapper)

Tags: java, json

I wonna merge two POJO objects:

```
MyBean old = new MyBean();
MyBean diff = new MyBean();
```

In Json they look this:

```
diff: {"nat_udp_update_time":333}
old: {"nat_udp_update_time":15,"static_sip_local_port":1111}
```

result needed:

```
old: {"nat_udp_update_time":333,"static_sip_local_port":1111}
```

How i make this with use ObjectMapper or another lib?

Comment: Do you mean old+diff translates to new Object?, you can do it in a program using ObjectMapper? what is the issue with that?

Comment: What is your entry point? Do you want to read two `JSON` files and merge them? Or, you have two beans, and need to merge them to one bean and then serialise to `JSON`? Do you have only primitive values, or maybe `MyBean` has another `POJO` classes? Could you please update your question and clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked quite a broad question. One way of solving this problem is to read the json into your bean objects with the object mapper and then go over the "diff" bean's members and put them into the new bean.

For example

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyBean old = mapper.readValue("{\"nat_udp_update_time\":15,\"static_sip_local_port\":1111}", MyBean.class);
MyBean diff = mapper.readValue("{\"nat_udp_update_time\":333}", MyBean.class);
// go over all the stuff in diff and set it in old if it's different
if (diff.getNatUdpUpdateTime() != null && !diff.getNatUdpUpdateTime().equals(old.getNatUdpUpdateTime())) {
    old.setNatUdpUpdateTime(diff.getNatUdpUpdateTime());
}
// and so on ...
```

You can look into a library like mapstruct if you're going to be doing lots of this stuff with beans. If your json is simple key-value pairs, consider using a `Map<String, Object>` instead of a `MyBean`. Note that the above example assumes you don't want to set `null` diff values.

Answer (score 0):

No dependencies need, you can use a bit of reflection.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public static <T> T merge(T a, T b) {
    try {
        if (a == null)
            return b;
        else if (b == null)
            return a;
        Class<T> type = (Class) a.getClass();
        T c = type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        for (Field field : a.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(a);
            field.set(c, value == null ? field.get(b) : value);
        }
        return c;
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot merge objects!", e);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, this will only merge fields declared in the given type, and your type will need an empty constructor for this.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Patch can do that for you. [Here an implem](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch).

Example:

```
JsonNode target = JsonPatch.apply(JsonNode patch, JsonNode source);
```